# Can I have multiple triggers that funnel into a single pipeline?

Tags: zapier

I've set up a simple Zap that whenever I make a commit on a given Github repo, and it contains a certain phrase, it'll tweet a link to that commit.

But the Github trigger makes me specify the exact repo.

What I'd like to do is have the look for the phrase in commits across several repos, all for the same phrase.

I could just set the Zap up several times - but what concerns me then - is if I want to later change the phrase, or the formatting of the Tweet, I'd have to do it for every Zap.

So is it possible to funnel multiple Zap triggers into a single pipeline?